# how can I handle eascpe chars with pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

My csv file is like this:

```
AcctId,"datetime","clid","src","dst"

1001,"2020-03-01 08:13:56","\"Angie\" <306>","306","93219009708"
```

use pandas to read normally

```
    data = pd.read_csv('1.csv', sep=',')
    print(data)
```

I can see the result in this way:

```
   AcctId             datetime             clid  src          dst
0    1001  2020-03-01 08:13:56  \Angie\" <306>"  306  93219009708
```

but I want to be in this way:

```
   AcctId             datetime         clid  src          dst
0    1001  2020-03-01 08:13:56  Angie <306>  306  93219009708
```

how can I handle with those escape chars.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may want to look into the string.strip() method... https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! What have you tried so far? For example: [Series.str.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) could fit the purpose

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `escapechar` to `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv', escapechar='\\')
```

Output:

```
   AcctId             datetime           clid  src          dst
0    1001  2020-03-01 08:13:56  "Angie" <306>  306  93219009708
```

Comment: yes, it is work as you shows, but I want to use convertes to strip that "" also. any idea ?

Comment: ```df['clid'] = df['clid'].str.replace('"', '')```